# Rails: Sidekiq Workers must be thread-safe. What Does it mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, model-view-controller, sidekiq

I read this about Sidekiq:

Sidekiq is multithreaded so your Workers must be thread-safe.

What does it mean? What is 'thread-safe' code? Can someone make example about that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Downvoted for being an off-topic on SO. Also, the answer to this question deserves a book, not a SO answer. You might easily find tons of information on the subject in search engines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a lot of possible ways to get non-thread safe code. Here is one example of the non-thread safe code:

```
# shared resource
$resource = StringIO.new

class NonThreadSafeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(_)
    random_letter = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample
    # concurrency problem: data race
    100_000.times do
      $resource.write random_letter
    end
  end
end

# Suppose you run 2 workers, result might be the next: "aaaabbabbabba..."
```

and it's thread safe complement:

```
require 'thread'

mutex = Mutex.new

class ThreadSafeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(_)
    random_letter = ('a'..'z').to_a.sample
    mutex.synchronize do
      # synchronize access to shared resource
      100_000.times do
        $resource.write random_letter
      end
    end
  end
end

# Suppose you run 2 workers, result must be the next: "aaaaaaa...bbbbbb..."
```

Pay attention, MRI GIL forces execution of the only one thread in a time at interpreter level. But that doesn't mean you will not meet concurrent issues similar to described above. JRuby and Rubinius are "true" concurrent execution environments, but less common, exactly because many libraries (including standard) should be rewritten with thread-safe in mind.

Sidekiq doesn't responsible of the libraries you are going to use inside the worker, but it [gracefully cautious](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#threading) you to understand consequences of using non-thread safe libraries.